# Show current user at top then other in slicer , Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Table -
[image]
and an another table like -
[image].

So I am applying filter for UserName in url(powerbi report server url) and filtering only 'XYZ'. I have to use Users as slicer. Now, if the filter value matches with the Users then "My view" else values present in Users Like -
[image]

NOTE : There is not relationship between the two tables.

Comment: can you elaborate bit more on - powerbi report server url

Comment: Actually am filtering UserName dataset with "XYZ" value. like -

https://reportserver/reports/powerbi/<report name>s?rs:Embed=true&filter= UserName/<Column> eq 'XYZ'

So that UserName table will have only one row i.e. 'XYZ'. It is for application integration usage only.

Comment: Your provided link is not working here.

Comment: That link is dummy. I just showed a way how I do filter a dataset using URL.